# Apply azure tagging policy to subscription level

Tags: azure, subscription, policy

I'am looking for a way to **audit** tags on subscription level using azure policy. For example: check if every subscription has the tag **environment** applied.

The built-in definitions only target resourcegroups, i'm wondering if it is possible to do the same for subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.
It's not required to select the resource group:

[image: Select Scope]

Comment: Hi markus, that's nog what i'm looking for. I want to audit the tag's that are set on the subscription itself. " For example: check if every subscription has the tag environment applied."

Comment: I know you can, but i want to audit that. i'm working with more than 50 subscriptions and need to audit wheter tags have been set

Comment: Got it. My subscription is marked as non-compliant


    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
          },
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        ]
      },